# In Windows copy a set of empty folders to a large number of differently-named subfolders

Tags: windows, copy, xcopy

I need to copy three empty folders (named say F1, F2 and F3) to a large number of subfolders.  These subfolders are several layers down in a tree of other folders. In other words, I have hundreds of folders, all with different names of the form XXXXX-XXXX, where the "X"s are different integers, each of which has several folders of the form nn-nn-nn, where the "n"s are also different integers.  I need the folders F1, F2 and F3 placed into each of the hundreds of nn-nn-nn subfolders.  Any help would be appreciated.

In other words, I want F1, F2 and F3 put in:

```
12345-6789>12-34-56
12345-6789>78-90-12
23456-7890>23-45-67
23456-7890>34-56-78
```

etc.

I don't know much about Windows programming or using Xcopy or robocopy, so please be patient in explaining how I can do this. Thanks very much.

I was able to copy the three empty folders (which are themselves contained in a folder called "folders") into the nn-nn-nn folders using this:

`for /d %i in (My Drive\??-??-??) do @xcopy "C:\My Drive\folders" "%i" /s /e /i`

but this doesn't work when those nn-nn-nn folders are themselves nested inside other folders (i.e., in the form \XXXXX-XXXX\nn-nn-nn")

Comment: Use parser for recursive folder list `for /f "delims=/" %i in ('dir /b /s "C:\My Drive\folders" /ad') do @echo "%i"`